# Correct authorization strategy using Azure AD to secure a CLI to REST API

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to implement security to a backoffice CLI tool (NodeJS) that calls a REST api (Java/JAX-RS) for performing database operations etc.
As we're using Azure AD for all our user accounts I'd like to use it for authenticating our users and also for authorization.

The authorization is needed since not all members of the AD is supposed to use the CLI, and there are two types of users of the CLI with a different set of available commands, meaning that even if you are able to use it, some features might be locked out depending if you are an operator or administrator.

I've managed to create two applications in Azure AD, one for the CLI and one for the API. I can login using our AD credentials, fetch Access tokens for the CLI app id requesting the REST API resouce. On the client side I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-oauth2 .
On the Java side the tokens are validated against Microsoft public keys, so everything seems to work out fine.

But, how should I lock down the users to either operator or admin roles? One naive way I can think of is to have the user/role correlation in the REST API and only use the OAuth flow for authenticating the user. But I guess that's what the AD is there for... Could OAuth scopes help me in this case?
Or should the REST API call the AD to query for users group memberships, once it receives the access tokens and knows the end user identity?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *Application Roles*.

Here you will find good description what application roles are and how to handle them:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps

The recommended resources at the end and also very helpful and will guide you through the process.

Also, when developing CLI it is recommended to use the Device Flow - [described here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-deviceprofile/) with [sample code (.net core) here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-deviceprofile).

Comment: Note the roles must be checked in the API. The CLI can also look at them but it really needs to be checked in the API since the CLI runs on the user's machine.

Comment: of course they must be checked in the API... they come as claim in the token ....

Comment: This is exactly the solution I found while experimenting. It's a shame that the Azure Portal does not have a UI for creating the roles, then I would probably have found out about them sooner. For the login I'm intending to run a simple express server as part of the CLI for dealing with the redirect and simply open up a browser to the login page.